# selenium - how to change current window location without closing the selenium window?

Tags: javascript, selenium, location, href, selenium-ide

I am using the seleniumIDE

I want a Test Case to go to another location based on a condition (note: the condition part is why I am using javascript and using the if-then plugin is not an option for now).  I have found that even `javascript{window.location.replace('http://google.com') }` closes my seleniumIDE window and replaces it with google but doesn't affect the actual window where the tests themselves were running.  I've replaced the condition itself with `1==1` i.e. true. to be simple

Right now I have:

```
Command  store
Target   javascript{if (1==1) {location="dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/users/sign_out"}}
Value    ignore_me
```

The problem right now is that this is closing the the seleniumIDE itself and opening a new window.

How can I change the URL location of the window where tests are running

Using:

- `this.location.href` gave an unexpected Exception
- `document.location.href` closed my selenium window and then opened a new window and visited the logout page (but original page in original window still logged in)
- `location.href` also closes my selenium window and open a new window with the logout action

Comment: Is it necessary to use javascript to perform this operation?

Comment: Yes it is due to the conditional and because I don't want to use the if-then plugin as I will be exporting the test cases to rspec.

Comment: Did you try `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: Yes but unfortunately that is acting on my seleniumIDE window, Not the window where the tests are running which remains open and logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but some magic is required. Use this.browserbot.openLocation in the target.
e.g. this.browserbot.openLocation('http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/');

```
Command  storeEval
Target   this.browserbot.openLocation('http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/');
Value    ignore_me
```

You might want to check out [Sel Blocks v1.3.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/versions/) and use the if/else around a normal open command.